# how to check the button works

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I know "ip" works but when I go to click the button I see nothing(the user is supposed to see nothing so this is great!) however, I don't know how I can verify the buttons ability.
The goal is to eventually have specified information from the button sent to a label widget(which the user will get to see)

```py
import tkinter as tk
import subprocess


ip = subprocess.run("ipconfig /all",universal_newlines=True,
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                       stderr=subprocess.PIPE)


#Setup for the window
window =tk.Tk()
window.title("Title_Name")
window.geometry("300x500")
x = window.winfo_x()
y = window.winfo_y()
sh = window.winfo_screenheight()
sw = window.winfo_screenwidth()
x_cord = int((sw/2)-550)
y_cord = int((sh/2)-300)
wh = 350
ww = 500
window.geometry("{}x{}+{}+{}".format(ww, wh ,x_cord, y_cord))



#widgets
button = tk.Button(window, text= "submit",
                   command = ip)

#widget placement
button.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5)
```

Comment: You are running the `ipconfig` command *once*, as your program is starting up.  The return value from `subprocess.run` is not a function that you can pass as the `command=` option of a Button.

Comment: @jasonharper Is it possible to do  subprocess.run("Input_goes_here") where I have a user input decide what code runs or is my only option to turn "ip" in to a function and call it as needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just quickly change command to a different function to test the command!

```
import tkinter as tk
import subprocess


ip = subprocess.run("ipconfig /all",universal_newlines=True,
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                       stderr=subprocess.PIPE)


#Setup for the window
window =tk.Tk()
window.title("Title_Name")
window.geometry("300x500")
x = window.winfo_x()
y = window.winfo_y()
sh = window.winfo_screenheight()
sw = window.winfo_screenwidth()
x_cord = int((sw/2)-550)
y_cord = int((sh/2)-300)
wh = 350
ww = 500
window.geometry("{}x{}+{}+{}".format(ww, wh ,x_cord, y_cord))

def ButtonTest():
   print('The button is working!')

#widgets
button = tk.Button(window, text= "submit",
                   command = ButtonTest)

#widget placement
button.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5)

tk.mainloop()
```

When you run this code and press the button it will print the output, so you can rest assured that assuming the ip function is working it will run!

Comment: Now I feel like I was just overthinking it. haha, Thanks for the help.